# Reading colors encoded in image at a position changes its value after decoded from video using php and ffmpeg

Tags: php, laravel, ffmpeg, terminal, sox

I created a piece of code to encode unique color on image and converted the image to PNG so that it would be lossless. After This I created a video with the frame using this image using the ffmpeg in php shellexec(). After saving this video I reopened it to extract the frmae image added and tried to read those values from the image. Now the values on the image are a bit changed.

Here is the code that I tried to create the video:

```
$canvas = imagecreatefromjpeg('translate/first_frame.jpg');
        // create a random color
        $rand = str_pad(dechex(rand(0x000000, 0xFFFFFF)), 6, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $dec_color= hexdec($rand);

        // add the new color to image

        for ($i=0; $i < 24; $i++) { 
           imagesetpixel($canvas,$i,0,$dec_color);
        }

        // store the image and close the file opened

        // $filename = 'translate/test/output.png'; 
        $filename = 'translate/test/output.bmp'; 

        // imagepng($canvas, $filename);
        imagebmp($canvas, $filename);

        imagedestroy($canvas);

        $frame      = $filename; // an image(png,gif,etc)
        $audio      = 'translate/output/audio/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxya.mp3';
        $output     = 'translate/output/video/'.time().'.mp4';   

        $cmd = 'ffmpeg -loop 1 -y -i '.$frame.' -i '.$audio.' -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -c:a copy -shortest '.$output;
        shell_exec($cmd);
```

This above code is creating the video with the image.

Now I tried to extract the image video and color from image, the colors are a bit changed.

```
if($request->hasFile('video')){
            $file = $request->file('video');
            $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $path = public_path('translate/test/');
        }else{
            return 'No file uploaded';
        }
        
        
        if ($file->move($path, $filename)) {
            $video = 'translate/test/'.$filename;
        }else{
            return 'error file upload';
        }

       
        // $output = 'translate/output/image/'.time().'.png';
        $output = 'translate/output/image/'.time().'.bmp';
        // $output = 'translate/output/image/'.time().'.jpg';

        $cmd = 'ffmpeg -i '.$video.' -vframes 1 '.$output;
        shell_exec($cmd);


// $dimg = imagecreatefrompng($output);
        $dimg = imageCreateFromBmp($output);
        // $dimg = imagecreatefromjpeg($output);

        $extracted_color = array();

        for ($x=0; $x < 24 ; $x++) { 
          $extracted_color[]= imagecolorat($dimg, $x, 0);
        }

        echo "<br>Retrived colors:<pre>".print_r($extracted_color,1)."</pre>";

        imagedestroy($dimg);
```

The color added was 44743072 but the colors retrieved are 4539914,4474121,4408072,4408326 from x=0,y=0 to x=24,y=0.

In both PNG and BMP I am loosing the added pixels. You can clearly see in my code i have commented the code for png to read the image as bmp.

Can someone let me know if I miss anything here.

Comment: PNG is lossless. MP4s are not.

Comment: So is there a solution that the image added in video can be retrieved losslessly?

Comment: No; the conversion to a video is inherently a lossy procedure. You'd need to use a lossless codec to perfectly preserve everything for a PNG --> video --> PNG workflow.

Comment: @ceejayoz could you please elaborate this with some example?

Comment: @ceejayoz  I have this which is already  libx264: ffmpeg -loop 1 -y -i image.png -i audiofile.mp3 -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -c:a copy -shortest output.mp4

Comment: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#LosslessH.264 would seem to indicate you need something like `-qp 0` for lossless.